# Getting input from user. Shell

Tags: c

I am writing my own simple shell and currently I'm thinking of getting input ( command ) from user.

I wrote a following prototype:

```
 while(1) {
        printf("gsh> ");
        fflush(stdout);
        total_len = 0;
        do {
            len = read(0, buffer,  MAX_LENGTH_OF_COMMAND-total_len -1);
            total_len+= len;
            } while( buffer[total_len-1] != '\n');
        buffer[total_len]='\0';
        parse(buffer);
    }
```

And this soultion seems me to be best, but I am not sure. So,  I am asking for correct and recommend/advice me something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `read` and `fread` are for reading fixed-size data. This is usually binary data which is organised in fixed-size blocks. You want to read lines of variable length. `fgets` is the function that does this for you. Or, if you want to write an interactive shell, you might consider unsing  `getline`, which can be coupled with acommand history and which allows advanced line editing.

Comment: Consider using `readline` ( https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html ).

Comment: What happens when `read` returns 0 or a negative value?

Answer (score 1):

You may rather use getchar() so you can be able to catch keys like up and down arrow (usually useful for shell history) that generate more than one character when you press it. You may also want to make your terminal as raw to get non blocking inputs.

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
  struct termios oldt;
  struct termios newt;

  tcgetattr(0, &oldt);
  memcpy(&newt, &oldt, sizeof(newt));
  cfmakeraw(&newt);
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &newt);
  /* your read function ...*/

  /* before exiting restore your term */                                                                   
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &oldt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way to create a custom prompt is using read. There is multiple ways so there is always a cleaner / better solution. But here is mine:

```
while ((fd = read(0, buff, BUFF_SIZE) > 0) {
    if (fd == BUFF_SIZE)
        // Command to big, handle this as you want to
    buff[fd - 1] = '\0';
    // Do what you want with your buff
}
```

Of course this solution has a max buffer size. You would need to wrap the read inside anoter function and use malloc to allocate the good size.